How to disable input buttons in seperate modes?
I have to code a calculator in JS and i want for exampe if i press the radio button "Binär" that i can only press the 0, 1 ; if i press "Dezimal" i cann press 0-9, but not A-F.
function onclickRadio(umrechnung)                               
> {
let displayZahl = Number(document.getElementById("textboxDisplay").value);

if(umrechnung == "Binär")
>   {
displayZahl = DezimalzahlZuBinaer(displayZahl);
modus = "Binär"
>   }

document.getElementById("textboxDisplay").value = displayZahl;

if(umrechnung == "hexa")
>   {
displayZahl = DezimalzahlZuHexa(displayZahl);
modus = "Hexa"
>   }

document.getElementById("textboxDisplay").value = displayZahl;

if(umrechnung == "dezimal")

displayZahl = BinaerZuDezimal(document.getElementById("textboxDisplay").value); 
modus = "dezimal"
>   }

document.getElementById("textboxDisplay").value = displayZahl;
> }
> </script>
> </head>

> <body>
>   <label> <input type = "radio" name = "Umrechnung" value = "hexa" onclick="onclickRadio('hexa')" /> Hexadezimal </label>
>   <label> <input type = "radio" name = "Umrechnung" value = "Binär" onclick="onclickRadio('Binär')" /> Binär </label>
>   <label> <input type = "radio" name = "Umrechnung" value = " Dezimal" onclick="onclickRadio('dezimal')" checked /> Dezimal  </label>
>   <input id="textboxDisplay" readonly />
>   <input type="button" value="1" onclick="AddLetter('1')" />
>   <input type="button" value="2" onclick="AddLetter('2')" />
>   <input type="button" value="3" onclick="AddLetter('3')" />
>   <input type="button" value="4" onclick="AddLetter('4')" />
>   <input type="button" value="5" onclick="AddLetter('5')" />
>   <input type="button" value="6" onclick="AddLetter('6')" />
>   <input type="button" value="7" onclick="AddLetter('7')" />
>   <input type="button" value="8" onclick="AddLetter('8')" />
>   <input type="button" value="9" onclick="AddLetter('9')" />
>   <input type="button" value="0" onclick="AddLetter('0')" />
>   <input type="button" value="A" onclick="AddLetter('A')" />
>   <input type="button" value="B" onclick="AddLetter('B')" />
>   <input type="button" value="C" onclick="AddLetter('C')" />
>   <input type="button" value="D" onclick="AddLetter('D')" />
>   <input type="button" value="E" onclick="AddLetter('E')" />
>   <input type="button" value="F" onclick="AddLetter('F')" />
>   <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Plus()" />
>   <input type="button" value="-" onclick="Minus()" />
>   <input type="button" value="*" onclick="Mal()" />
>   <input type="button" value="/" onclick="Geteilt()" />
>   <input type="button" value="Mod" onclick="Restwert()" />
>   <input type="button" value="Löschen" onclick="Weg()" />
>   <input type="button" value="=" onclick="Gleich()" />
> </body>

i tried <button disabled> , but than its permanent disbaled. i just want to disable it when i am in the different mode.

To enable the buttons belonging to the selected base and disable all the other ones, you need a strategy that will be triggered when the click event occurs on those radio button options (binary/decimal/hex).
In particular regarding to that aspect, I used the classes digit base2 base10 base16 on  those buttons so that by using basic css selectors I could, each time, first disable all of them, and then enable only those belonging to the selected base 2, 10, 16.
//disable all the .digit elements
document.querySelectorAll('.digit')
  .forEach(el => el.disabled = true);
                      
//enable all the .digit elements having the selected base    
document.querySelectorAll(`.digit.base${selectedBase}`)
  .forEach(el => el.disabled = false); 

But in general I had to rewrite your logic in the slimmest way possible mainly addressing the followings:

adding event handlers using addEventListener instead of inline event
handlers because it's not
reccomended
to mix javascript code with html.
Using css classes digit base16 base10 base2 to declare to which
base belonged each digit button.. so to have a convenient way to
discern which one to enable/disable according to the selected base;
Using
parseInt
to parse a string returning the corresponding number according to the
radix (base);
Using
Number.toString
to convert a number to string according to the radix (base);



const number = document.getElementById("number");

//selects all the .digit elements
document.querySelectorAll('.digit')
  //for each one of them (as el)
  .forEach( el => {
    //adds the click event handler
    el.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
      const digit = event.target.value;
      if(number.value == '0')
        number.value = '';      
      number.value += digit;
    })
  });

//selects all the input[name="mode"]
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="mode"]')
  //for each one of them (as el)
  .forEach( el => {
    //adds the click event handler
    el.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    
      //the base selected from the radio button triggering the event
      const selectedBase = event.target.value;
      
      //disable all the .digit elements
      document.querySelectorAll('.digit').forEach(el => el.disabled = true);
      
      //enable all the .digit elements having the selected base
      document.querySelectorAll(`.digit.base${selectedBase}`).forEach(el => el.disabled = false);  
      
      //parse the number in the input box using its stated base
      const currentNumber = parseInt(number.value, number.dataset.base);
      //rewrite the number in the input box using the selected base
      number.value = currentNumber.toString(selectedBase).toUpperCase();
      
      //save the selected base in the data-base attribute
      number.dataset.base = selectedBase;      
    })
  });
input[type="radio"],
input[type="button"]
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
<label>Hexadecimal</label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="16">
<br>
<label>Binary</label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="2">
<br>
<label>Decimal</label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="10" checked>

<br>
<br>

<input id="number" data-base="10" value="0" readonly>

<input type="button" value="0" class="digit base16 base10 base2">
<input type="button" value="1" class="digit base16 base10 base2">
<input type="button" value="2" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="3" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="4" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="5" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="6" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="7" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="8" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="9" class="digit base16 base10">
<input type="button" value="A" class="digit base16">
<input type="button" value="B" class="digit base16">
<input type="button" value="C" class="digit base16">
<input type="button" value="D" class="digit base16">
<input type="button" value="E" class="digit base16">
<input type="button" value="F" class="digit base16">

<br>
<br>

<input type="button" value="+" onclick="Plus()" disabled>
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="Minus()" disabled>
<input type="button" value="*" onclick="Mal()" disabled>
<input type="button" value="/" onclick="Geteilt()" disabled>
<input type="button" value="Mod" onclick="Restwert()" disabled>
<input type="button" value="Löschen" onclick="Weg()" disabled>
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="Gleich()" disabled>



